# Setting a certain word to a value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am new to coding in SQL and have come across a time consuming problem. We have a very long query where a certain date is being mentioned many times. I know it it is possible to write in every date manually but it is mentioned around 30 times. Is it possible to set a word/value to the date I want to use which mean I only have to write in the date once? The ones I have found so far only change the data in the tables which I do not want, only in the query!

Something along the line with "Set USED_DATE to ..." See below for example;

---

USED_DATE= '2019-12-31'

SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE latest_date= USED_DATE

SELECT * 
FROM Country
WHERE latest_date = USED_DATE

SELECT * 
FROM Jobs
WHERE latest_date = USED_DATE

Etc...

Comment: You may use user-defined variable. But you must execute all queries in the same connection.

Comment: *We have a very long query where a certain date is being mentioned many times.* In ONE query? or in a lot of queries as shown below?

Comment: Pl provide more information about, how you are running/executing the group of queries? Are you doing through stored procedure, any programming language or any other way?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (The answer will perhaps not be the same...)

Comment: Try stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for PostgreSQL with psql (CLI):

```
$ cat tparm.sh
psql -e -v used_date="'02-29-2020'" -f tparm.sql
$ cat tparm.sql
select * from t1 where c=:used_date;
select * from t2 where c=:used_date;
select * from t3 where c=:used_date;
$ ./tparm.sh
select * from t1 where c='02-29-2020';
 c 
---
(0 rows)

select * from t2 where c='02-29-2020';
 c 
---
(0 rows)

select * from t3 where c='02-29-2020';
 c 
---
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot depend on psql's variables, you could use a temp view, or an SQL  function(these can both be inlined):

---

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TEMP VIEW view_date AS
SELECT '2020-01-01'::date AS this_date
        ;


CREATE FUNCTION this_date(OUT date )
-- RETURNS DATE
AS
$func$
SELECT '2020-01-01'::date
$func$
LANGUAGE SQL immutable
        ;

EXPLAIN
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
FROM public.tweeps twp
WHERE twp.created_at >= this_date()
        ;

EXPLAIN
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
FROM public.tweeps twp
JOIN view_date v ON twp.created_at >= v.this_date
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE VIEW
CREATE FUNCTION
                            QUERY PLAN                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=489.06..489.07 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Seq Scan on tweeps twp  (cost=0.00..489.02 rows=16 width=0)
         Filter: (created_at >= '2020-01-01'::date)
(3 rows)

                            QUERY PLAN                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=489.06..489.07 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Seq Scan on tweeps twp  (cost=0.00..489.02 rows=16 width=0)
         Filter: (created_at >= '2020-01-01'::date)
(3 rows)
```